# Flutter - How to update the user information using a controller?

Tags: flutter, api, dart, controller

I don't have that much experience with Flutter.

I'm creating an account information page. On that page, users can update their details. I have created the required API services and controllers.

When I run the code I get the below error.

```
Too many positional arguments: 0 allowed, but 6 found.
Try removing the extra positional arguments.
    productController.customerUpdate(
                                    ^
```

How to solve this?

API services:

```
Future<Response?> customerUpdate(String? email, String? firstName, 
      String? lastName, String? phone, String? customerAccessToken) async {
    var uri = '$_url/update-customer';
    print(uri);
    // String token = box.read('token');

    // dio.options.headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer $token";
    try {
      final response = await dio.patch(uri, data: {
        'email': email,
        'firstName': firstName,
        'lastName': lastName,
        'phone': phone,
        'customerAccessToken': box.read('token')
      });
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        box.write('token', response.data['token']);
        box.write('information_updated', true);
      }
      return response;
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      debugPrint(e.response.toString());
      return e.response;
    }
  }
```

Product controller:

```
customerUpdate({
      @required String? email,
      String? firstName,
      String? lastName,
      String? phone,
      String? customerAccessToken,
      context}) async {
    loader('Saving...');
    dio.Response? response = await remoteServices.customerUpdate(
        email, firstName, lastName, phone, customerAccessToken);

    if (response!.statusCode == 200) {
      Get.back();
      Get.back();
      myDialog.showFloatingFlushbar(
          context, 
          'Information Updated', Color(0xff734FE0), Color(0xff734FE0));
    } else {
      myDialog.showFloatingFlushbar(context, 'Please check the errors above',
          Colors.red.shade800, Colors.red.shade700);
    }
  }
```

Code:

```
final box = GetStorage();

  final TextEditingController _emailController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _firstNameController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _lastNameController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _phoneController = TextEditingController();
  
  customerUpdate() {
    productController.customerUpdate(
        email: _emailController.text,
        firstName: _firstNameController.text,
        lastName: _lastNameController.text,
        phone: _phoneController.text,
        customerAccessToken: box.read('token'),
        context: context);
  }
```

Comment: Did you save your ProductController file? Looks like you added the parameters and all the logic, but the changes are not applied.